# Difficulty creating a mysql search query and displaying results

Tags: php, mysql, search, superglobals

OK- I have been wrestling with this issue for a couple days now. I've searched google and stackoverflow and other places and I've tried lots of things to try to make this work but no luck thus far. I attribute this to my noob-ness to php and mysql, as I've probably misplaced a } or done something out of order in the code.

The scenario: I am trying to use a form to generate a search query and display the results. This is attempting to search my single-table database. Also, this is all on a closed network, so I'm not worried right now about injection/security vulnerabilities.

The problem originated when I was trying to write the search function and got to learn about how you can't use $_POST anymore because it's a superglobal.

Right now it's not generating any errors when I try to use the search form, so I'm really stumped as to how to get it to work.

EDIT: I'm recycling a lot of the code from the form I used to create the records. Hopefully that isn't a mistake.

Here's the code:

```
    <?php
if(isset($_POST['search']))
{
$dbhost = 'localhost';
$dbuser = 'root';
$dbpass = '';
$conn = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass);
if(! $conn )
{
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}

if(! get_magic_quotes_gpc() )
{
   $Client = addslashes ($_POST['Client']);
   $Product = addslashes ($_POST['Product']);
   $Type = addslashes ($_POST['Type']);
   $Date = addslashes ($_POST['Date']);
   $Category = addslashes ($_POST['Category']);
   $Disc = addslashes ($_POST['Disc']);
}
else
{
   $Client =  ($_POST['Client']);
   $Product =  ($_POST['Product']);
   $Type =  ($_POST['Type']);
   $Date =  ($_POST['Date']);
   $Category =  ($_POST['Category']);
   $Disc =  ($_POST['Disc']);
}
//search function!
function search_designarchive($_post) {
    $Client = $_post['Client'];
    $Product = $_post['Product'];
    $Type = $_post['Type'];
    $Date = $_post['Date'];
$Category = $_post['Category'];
$Disc = $_upost['Disc'];

    //is this where 'real escaping' should be?
    mysql_select_db('desarch');
$query = "SELECT * FROM designarchive";
$conditions = array();

if($Client !="") {
  $conditions[] = "Client='$Client'";
}
if($Product !="") {
  $conditions[] = "Product='$Product'";
}
if($Type !="") {
  $conditions[] = "Type='$Type'";
}
if($Date !="") {
  $conditions[] = "Date='$Date'";
}
if($Category !="") {
  $conditions[] = "Category='$Category'";
}
if($Disc !="") {
  $conditions[] = "Disc='$Disc'";
}

$sql = $query;
if (count($conditions) > 0) {
  $sql .= " WHERE " . implode(' AND ', $conditions);
}

$result = mysql_query($sql, $conn) or die(mysql_error());

return $result;
if(! $result )
{
  die('Result query did not work: ' . mysql_error());
}
    }

mysql_close($conn);
}

else
{
?>
```

And here is the form:

```
<form method="post" action="<?php $_PHP_SELF ?>">
<table width="400" border="0" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="2">
<tr>
<td width="100">Client</td>
<td><input name="Client" type="text" id="Client" size="40"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td width="100">Product</td>
<td><input name="Product" type="text" id="Product" size="40"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td width="10">Type</td>
<td><input type="radio" name="Type" value="Sold" id="Type"> Sold<br>
<input type="radio" name="Type" value="Spec" id="Type"> Spec<br>
<input type="radio" name="Type" value="Marketing" id="Type"> Marketing<br></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td width="6">Date</td>
<td><input name="Date" type="text" id="Date" size="6" maxlength="6"> <i>ex. Oct-13</i>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td width="100">Category</td>
<td><input name="Category" type="text" id="Category"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td width="3">Disc #</td>
<td><input name="Disc" type="text" id="Disc" size="4" maxlength="3"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td width="100"> </td>
<td> </td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td width="100"> </td>
<td>
<input name="search" type="submit" id="search" value="Search">
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
<?php
}
?>
```

Thanks in advance for any help. This community has been a great resource. This is actually the first time I've asked a question however :)

Comment: I don't see where your PHP program uses the results of your query. Am I missing something?

Comment: In current code there is no problems, it just do not print results :) so give us part of code which actually do this. Just notice - swap return $result; with if next to it - it will make more sense

Comment: Well, that certainly would explain why nothing is happening. I have tried print $result; and echo $result; but it's still not generating any output. Which command should I use to get it to display the results? Do I need to assign another variable before the $sql = command? Thanks everyone :)